# Using non-English letters: "error: illegal character" while compiling with javac

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, cyrillic

I'm writing a simple program which translates phrases from Russian to Morse code, and I have trouble using cyrillic characters in my switch statement. Here's an example of the code:

```
switch (letter) {
   case 'А':
      morse_message.append(".- ");
      break;
   case 'Б':
      morse_message.append("-... ");
      break;
   case 'Ц':
      morse_message.append("-.-. ");
      break;
   ...
```

At first, it didn't compile at all writing something like this:

> Morse.java:23: error: unclosed character literal
> case '╨С':
> ^
> Morse.java:23: error: illegal character: '\u2018'
> case '╨С':

Then I made some research and tried to compile it with `javac -encoding UTF-8 Morse`. It worked, but when I execute the code, it just ignores the cyrillic letters. For example, if the translated message is *Привет!*, it will only show the Morse code for the exclamation mark.

Any ideas how to fix it? I've read a lot about character encoding, and I feel completely lost. The default encoding, which I checked with `Charset.defaultCharset()`, is **windows-1252**, and it should work just fine with Russian alphabet. Can it be an IDE problem?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but here's one thing you can do to help debug it. Print out the numerical values of the cyrillic and see if they match the unicode values. System.out.println(Integer.toHexString((int) 'Б'));

Comment: This is an encoding mis-match.  You are going to need to determine how the Cyrillic characters are encoded in the input stream, AND, how you entered the characters into your program, AND how your program source is encoded (cp-1251?).  All three have to match for this to work.

Comment: [As you can see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set), windows-1252 does not have any characters from the Russian alphabet. `'╨С'` in the error message probably means your file is UTF-8, but you haven’t told the compiler that your file is UTF-8.